# Function that returns the rightmost node in the bottom level of a complete Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, heap, binary-search-tree

I just need help writing a recursive function that returns the rightmost node at the deepest level of a binary search tree (it's actually a node based heap). It is important to remember that the tree will always be complete. I have tried a few things, but nothing worked well enough to post here as a start.

I have found similar questions but those all relate to the leftmost node which I can do because it is always in the same place, but the rightmost node varies depending on how filled the tree is.

I have functions getLeftHeight and getRightHeight

```
void HeapClass::findDeleteNode( HeapNode *&workingPtr ){

}
```

I have the prototype like this, where I send in a pointer that I later take values out of and delete in a different function. I'm new to this website so sorry if this question is lacking information or posted incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow.  Here's some guidelines on writing good... questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I think you will need to post more code to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare the height of the left subtree and the right. If the height of the right one is greater or equal to the left, you recurse on that node, otherwise on the left

```
void HeapClass::findDeleteNode( HeapNode *&workingPtr )
{
     bool isLeaf = getLeftHeight(workingPtr)) == 0 && getRightHeight(workingPtr) == 0;
     if(isLeaf) {
         // found it
         return;
     }

     findDeleteNode(getLeftHeight(workingPtr) > getRightHeight(workingPtr) ? workingPtr->left : workingPtr->right);
}
```